# Datepicker initialization for class fields added after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have fields where multiple extra fields can be added after the page loads (think education & work experience fields on job resumes). I am using [this](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

I can add a datepicker on the first field, but subsequent added fields do not access the datepicker, despite being cloned/essential duplicates of the original. I'm guessing that the datepicker only intializes on page load or for only one class on the page.

So on a page I initialize the datepicker:

```
$('.input-append.date').datepicker();
```

for a block of form code encapsulated by this class. OK for initial page load; and also OK if there is an error and the page reloads multiple fields previously input(there is a datepicker for all fields returned with any error). However, with another js function that adds new fields to the form, additional new fields do not have access to the datepicker. I do not see how to do this now, perhaps someone with more experience/wisdom can provide me a hint.

EDIT:

Simple enough: I simply added:

```
 $('.input-append.date').datepicker();
```

to the code calling the new field. As to being the optimal solution I do not know, anyone who specializes in js can comment on that, and there are many other similar questions here I found once I expanded my search terms. However, good enough for me now in what I'm doing.

Comment: You need to initialise the datepicker on each dynamically added element after they are appended to the DOM. E.g. `myElem.appendChild(newTexInputElem); $(newTextInputElem).datepicker()`

Comment: That is what I guessed after initial diagnosis, but not entirely sure how to go about that.

Comment: Just try what I wrote above. I suppose subsequently added fields are attached to the DOM by `appendChild` (or jQuery `append`). After the append, you have to call `datepicker()` on the element just appended. You could call you original `$('.input-append.date').datepicker();` but that would try to initialise datepickers already initialised. So better is to call `datepicker` individually on the appended elements.

Comment: If you post your code, I can give an example.

Answer (score 0):

For elements which are being added on fly use data-provide="datepicker" attribute. It will be initialized lazily. For example if an input field is coming up in an ajax response and loaded in a container div. So in this case:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" />
```

so when when you will load this ajax response it in cotainer div like

```
$('#container-div').html(ajax_response);
```

this will work.

In the same way if you are creating an element through jquery and appending it to some container (**I think this is happening in your case**), for example you have a function that creates textbox and append it to some container div and this function is called on click event of some element let's say it's button. Again data-provide attribute is the solution to this problem. For example

```
function createTextBox(){
    var t = $('<input>').attr('data-provide','datepicker');
    $('#container-div').append(t);
}
```

And this function is called on click event of some button like in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#someBtn).click(createTextBox);
});
```

In short whether that dynamic element is coming in **ajax response as a string or being created through jquery**, just use **data-provide** attribute to set bootstrap datepicker. Because in this case datepicker is initialized lazily in Bootstrap fashion.